# How to change the program syntax with ArrayList option?

Tags: java, arraylist

The program generates 3 rectangles (default w and h values are 1.0). After the generated rectangles I call getArea() function to calculate its area, and getPerimeter() function to calculate its perimeter.

So I want to use ArrayList instead of Rectangle[] Array type.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[3];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter the width and the height? (Y/N)");

            char choice = input.next().charAt(0);
            if (choice == 'y')
                rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble());

            else
                rectangles[i] = new Rectangle();


        }
        System.out.println("The rectangles are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Rectangle " + (i + 1) +
                            ": width: " + rectangles[i].getWidth() +
                            ", height " + rectangles[i].getHeight());
            System.out.println("Area is: " + rectangles[i].getArea());
            System.out.println("Perimeter is: " + rectangles[i].getPerimeter());
        }
    }
```

How I think I should start: Firstly I will put a scanner input to ask how many Rectangles do I need, then with a for loop I want to generate the rectangles in the list. What could be the solution to resolve it in an ArrayList? Thanks a lot in advance!

I don't know the type of the ArrayList because it needs 2 variables, but I suppose they have to be double. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on using generic types.  Hint: the type of an ArrayList of Rectangle objects will be `ArrayList<Rectangle>`.  But you will also need to declare the `Rectangle` class.

Comment: It’s not clear what your actual question is. If you’re just wanting to change the array to an ArrayList, you can declare it as `List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();`. Then when you want to access an element by index , in your loop for example, you call `rectangles.get(i)`. Since ArrayList isn’t a fixed size, you don’t need to ask how many to make ahead of time. You could have a do-while loop that prompts the user for dimensions, creates the rectangle object, and add it to the list. Then ask if they want to add another rectangle and the input will determine if it runs again.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your modifiable list rather than array.

```
// Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[3];
List< Rectangle > rectangles = new ArrayList<>() ;
```

No need to specify a length as the size of a modifiable list is not predetermined. You may optionally specify an initial capacity.

Since the list size is not predetermined, change your `for` loop to a `while` loop. Test user’s input to indicate their intention to stop creating rectangles. Flip a boolean flag value when the user so indicates.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
boolean go = true ;
while ( go ) {
```

Add new rectangles to your list.

```
// rectangles[i] = new Rectangle( input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble() );
rectangles.add( new Rectangle( input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble() ) ) ;
```

By the way, I recommend gathering your inputs *before* calling the `Rectangle` constructor.

To access all the elements in the list, use *for-each* syntax.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
for ( Rectangle rectangle : rectangles ) {
```

Regarding this line:

```
"Rectangle " + (i + 1) +
```

… if you care about distinguishing between rectangles, you should add a third member field to the class defining `Rectangle`. Common choices include a sequential integer number or a [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

```
record Rectangle ( UUID id , double width , double height ) {}
…
rectangles.add( new Rectangle( UUID.randomUUID() , input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble() ) ) ;
```